# UIWebview inside uitableview and scrolls contrary to the uitableview's scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have UIWebview inside a UITableview. 
I want when my tableView scrolls to bottom of the screen and when we reach the cell of UIWebview, my webview scrolls content to top in order to show its content to the user.
so the webview should scroll its content automatically when mytableview scrolls .

**UPDATE : Explanation**

In fact, this is my problem : 
I want that my webview (which is inside a cell indexpath = 2) scrolls to top so we will have its y negative value  in order to show its content while the tableview scrolls to bottom

Comment: this is rough. you're playing with fire trying to do this. depending on how complex this functionality needs to be, you're going to have to observe values of both scroll views at once in a master observer and tinker with the values of each while passing delegates back and forth to super classes and sub classes. i won't even go further than this because the task is too complex for SO Q/A format. i'd rethink the design requirement.

Comment: hello @Loxx can you explain more ?